# Showing WMS layer data and marker popup simultaneously in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, wms, getfeatureinfo

I need to show WMS layer information and if there are some marker
or other layers at the same coordinate, it should show both
data of WMS layer and marker information.
But when marker covers wms layer, click would not trigger getfeatureinfo
to get WMS data. Is there any method to show both?

My marker:

```
L.marker([lat,lng], { icon: icons }).bindPopup(
         '<table><thead><tr><th>test</th></tr></thead ><tbody align="center"><tr><td>context</td></tr>'
         ).openPopup();
```

I write a sample on codepen:
https://codepen.io/jerry820428/pen/zYKRERE

I want to trigger map.on('click') event when click the marker, that means both alert and popup would show on web.

Comment: Do you want this marker to be interactive, meaning, do you want it to react on click or mouse over? If not, just use option `interactive: false` when you create it.

Comment: I need the marker to be interactive. Both wms layer and marker has popup contents, but I don't know how to show both when I click the intersection area. When I do so, only information of marker would be displayed, wms didn't trigger click event to get layer information.

Comment: Then the simplest solution would be to catch `map.on('click', ...)` event, since it gets fired always, regardless of any other event handlers, tied to various layer elements.

Comment: I write a demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/jerry820428/pen/zYKRERE
It seems map.on event didn't trigger when I clicked the marker. Did I miss options or something to show trigger both?

Comment: You are right, I was a bit careless when testing. I checked for several events simultaneously and then missed that it did not fire `click` event on map. See solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mouse `click` event gets caught by marker popup handler and does not reach the map, solution is to fire map `click` event yourself inside marker `click` event handler.

Code could then look something like this:

```
marker.on('click', function(evt) {
  map.fire('click', evt, false);
});
```

Comment: That's what I need !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to display `wms` and/or `geojson` layers as many as you need. Please notice `wms` uses pre-defined styles defined on mapserver or geoserver through separate `.sld` files but `geojson` layer is styled in client side through `.json` object.

```js
var wmsLayer1 = L.tileLayer.wms(url1, { ... });
var wmsLayer2 = L.tileLayer.wms(url2, { ... });
var vectorLayer1 = L.geoJSON(feactures1, { ... });
var vectorLayer1 = L.geoJSON(feactures2, { ... });

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [lat, long],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [
        wmsLayer1,
        wmsLayer2,
        vectorLayer1,
        vectorLayer2
    ]
});
```

**In case of displaying multiple layers, consider order of layers.**

Displaying and hiding popup on markers is possible by adding listener to vector layer that capture user interactions:

```js
vectorLayer1.on('click', this._onLayerClick);

//React JS
_onLayerClick = (e) => {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    const { mapObject } = this.state;
    mapObject.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer === e.layer) {
            layer.setStyle(touchStyle);
            layer.bindTooltip('', {
                sticky: true,
                direction: 'top',
                offset: L.point([0, -10])
            })
            layer.setTooltipContent(`Name: ${e.layer.feature.properties.name}`)
            layer.openTooltip();
            return true;
         }
    })
}
```

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382377/67659) I explained other events.

[refrences]

- https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html
- https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/
- https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/